# Not able to access a sub webpage aspx from same directory

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I put
 `Context.RewritePath("/users/abc/default.aspx", False)`

in Global.asax Application_BeginRequest

and when i hit **www.mydomain.com** then it open the user default.aspx page as i want..
(original location is **www.mydomain.com/users/abc/default.aspx**).

Now the problem is there is a file name profile.aspx  at same location /users/abc/profile.aspx(the real location is **www.mydomain.com/users/abc/profile.aspx**) and it is not working.

i try to open  **www.mydomain.com/profile.aspx, www.mydomain.com/users/abc/profile.aspx** but these are not link it or open it live... where i am doing wrong?

Comment: This is not really clear: What is not working? What do you expect and what do you get?